# ASP.NET Missing (or Invisible) Controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been handed an existing ASP.NET project for maintenance purposes by a now-departed developer. I'm relatively new to ASP.NET, though not MVCs in general. I now have to make a change to a $post function. The function itself looks exactly like it should (and indeed, it functions correctly currently), but it seems to be calling a Controller that doesn't exist in the file structure. Actually, no Controllers are in the file structure (or Models, for that matter, but Views are exactly as expected).

Before I march to devops and accuse them of not giving me sufficient access to *see* the Controller, I thought I'd ask here: is there some non-standard way of placing Controllers in the file structure? And if that's the case, how would I be able to go about finding them?

Comment: You probably need to check routing, start with `global.asax.cs` file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: I'm investigating. There is no global.asax.cs file, though there is a global.asax pointing me at a .dll. Down the rabbit hole I go.